# Huawei Map Is not Drawn or Painted

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am currently developing a demo test, integrating the example done in android studio as an FFI in another software development tool called Kony Quantum Visualizer, it is a tool used to develop apps for mobile devices, desktop Web, among others.

I have managed to advance the integration between the code made in android studio and following the steps of the Huawei Code Lab for the Map Kit, and in fact the application when compiling it from my tool compiles without problems. When running on a Huawei device Model: Mate 20 / Android 10 / EMUI 10.0.0, it runs but is not drawing the map, but it does paint my location points or other test markers, but the map does not draw it, just place the quadrants.

Important note:

> This device is a Huawei, however it is one of these models that is still associated with Google services. This has no bearing on these tests, correct?

> In the tests of the Code Lab generated from Android studio, and tested on the same device, if you draw the map with the test points as well.

> Should it be tested only on a device that is no longer associated with Google services? or does this not influence anything?

> Within the lines captured in the Log, you can see some failed, that I cannot understand what they refer to or if they are tied to this just that I did not draw the Map.

Attached I am uploading the following:

1. Log captured from the device at the time of testing.
2. Image of how the test is displayed on the device.

[image: Log]

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your map bundles are added before loading the map

```
  Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle("MapViewBundleKey");
}
```

If this solution did not work check your apk signature (sha256 key). This problem occurs when your sha256 signature of apk is not matching with the apk signature in the developer console.